# Update join not updating the same number of rows as equivelant select

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, sql-update

When I run this SELECT statement, I receive 642 rows...

```
SELECT *
FROM _DevLoadIn a
JOIN ArticleCompanyList b ON b.Company = a.Name
```

When I run this UPDATE statement, only 630 rows are updated...

```
UPDATE b
SET b.BGCompanyId = a.RelatedId
FROM _DevLoadIn a
JOIN ArticleCompanyList b ON b.Company = a.Name
```

The JOIN is identical, so how can the number of effected rows be different?  Both statements execute without error.  I don't see how this could be possible.  Can anyone provide any insight?  Am I missing something about how an update/join works?

Comment: do b.Company and a.Name have same type and length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best guess is that there are more matches in A for each value of B.  So the `select` statement returns the joined duplicates of A - but the `update` only updates the row once.

In other words, the additional values in your select are representations of B (not A).

---- updated post question edit -----

Are you sure that your are updating the right value?  Make sure that the proper table (A or B) is on the left hand side of the update statement.  It appears you've edited your question and switched places of what was originally posted.  The theory is still the same however.

Comment: I won't upvote because I'm not sure but that would be my best guess too.

Comment: Just checked and you are right.  So an update select won't work with duplicates in the join?  I guess I will have to use a cursor.

Comment: You shouldn't have to use a cursor.  The update will apply to all matches found as long as the right table is getting updated according to the structure of the query.

Comment: Spot on!  The one thing I didn't check was duplicates in my _DevLoadIn table (the data was supposed to be unique).  And of course there are 12 duplicate companies - once I clear those up I should be good.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If b.BGCompanyId is already equal to a.RelatedId, it will not show as updated.

You could verify this by modifying your original query like so:

`SELECT *

    FROM _DevLoadIn a

    JOIN ArticleCompanyList b ON b.Company = a.Name

    WHERE b.BGCompanyID != a.RelatedId`